# Using Selenium Grid 2 with PHPUnit tests

Tags: phpunit, selenium-grid

I have recently written a lot of selenium 1 tests for a fairly complex project. They are all written in php and run smoothly on the selenium-server 1.0.7.

Obviously with firefox 5 (and 6 released today) selenium server 1.0.7 is not working anymore. I've tried, but the server is just opening blank windows.

Now I am trying to get those tests running on selenium grid. I managed to get a hub and a couple of remote-controls runnnig using grid v1, but they only open blank windows just like the old server did. So I figured i needed to upgrade to grid v2.

For some reason i can get the clients connected to the hub, but if I try running my tests against the hub it doesn't seem to be able to connect at all ("PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Could not connect to the Selenium RC server"). I tried running them against selenium standalone server 2.4.0 and that does seem to work.

I read in a forum, that selenium grid 2 just doesn't work with phpunit (yet?).

How can i get my tests running on a grid? What is missing for phpunit to connect to the server? I appreciate any help!

I set up the hub as follows:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.4.0.jar -role hub
```

And two slaves:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.4.0.jar -role rc -hub http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register -port 5555
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.4.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register -port 5556
```

Everything seems to be working till here as i see two nodes in the grid console (http://localhost:4444/grid/console).

So here is all the initialization I am doing in code:

```
<?php

require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php';

class Grid_Test extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
    public $captureScreenshotOnFailure = false;

    public static $browsers = array(
        'FFLinux' => array(
            'name'      => 'Firefox on Linux',
            'browser'   => '*firefox',
            'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'      => 4444,
            'timeout'   => 30000
        ));

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.google.com');
    }

    public function testGridWorking()
    {

        $this->open('/');
        $this->assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

This code still works on the standalone server 2.4.0. It fails at the last line as expected.

The Exception seems to be thrown in PHPUnit/Extentions/SeleniumTestCase/Driver.php. There seems to be the problem.

```
protected function doCommand($command, array $arguments = array())
{
    $url = sprintf(
      'http://%s:%s/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=%s',
      $this->host,
      $this->port,
      urlencode($command)
    );

    [...]

    $handle = @fopen($url, 'r', FALSE, $context);
    if (!$handle) {
        throw new PHPUnit_Framework_Exception(
            'Could not connect to the Selenium RC server.'
        );
    }
    [...]
}
```

When i request http://localhost:4444/selenium-driver/driver in the browser, i get:

```
    HTTP ERROR: 500
    org.openqa.grid.internal.GridException: Session not available - []
    RequestURI=/selenium-server/driver
```

Any idea how to fix this? Do I need to change that url maybe ?

Comment: Can you post your initializTion code i.e the code that does the setup??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also make sure you have setup the Grid correctly here is a small post that shows how it is done : http://opensourcetester.co.uk/2011/07/06/selenium-grid-2/

BTW I dint see code that does the driver instantiation.. Am i missing something?

Here is how it is done:

```
require_once "phpwebdriver/WebDriver.php";
require("phpwebdriver/LocatorStrategy.php");

$webdriver = new WebDriver("localhost", "4444");
$webdriver->connect("firefox");                            
$webdriver->get("http://google.com");
$element = $webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::name, "q");
$element->sendKeys(array("selenium google code" ) );
$element->submit();

$webdriver->close();
```

for more: http://code.google.com/p/php-webdriver-bindings/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I read that before and that's exactly how I do it.

Comment: Apparently the PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase does not support Selenium 2.0 yet. Those bindings you linked to don't work for me either. But I got something to work on, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with trying to use PHPUnit with Selenium Grid 2 has already been reported to the project owners. Have a look at the patch available [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2105#c5) to see if it works for you.

Anyway, if I were you I would start thinking about migrating to WebDriver through one of the drivers available out there for PHP, like [php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver).